# How to set PAGES property in YAHOO.widget.CalendarGroup for different case?

Tags: javascript, mobile, calendar, yui

I meet a problem when doing the ***YAHOO.widget.CalendarGroup***.
I want to do it like this, if the page widtha is less than 720px, the CalendarGroup PAGES property is 1
 [image], 
if more than 720px, the CalendarGroup use the default PAGES property is 2[image].
I use

```
myCalendar.cfg.setProperty("PAGES",1);
```

but it doesn't work, I found in the document here: 
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.CalendarGroup.html#config_pages

> pages - Number
>   The number of pages to include in the CalendarGroup. This value can only be set once, in the CalendarGroup's constructor arguments.
>   Default Value: 2

Seems we can't change the pages property after the initicalization. How could I change the pages based on the change of my browser width? THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

As it says: "This value can only be set once, in the CalendarGroup's constructor arguments". Use the constructor, like this:

```
var myCalObject = new YAHOO.widget.CalendarGroup(
    calObject, 
    calObject + "Container", 
    { pages: 2, close: true, iframe: false }
);
```